# What is the practical usage difference between "grep -e" and "grep"?

Tags: grep

I have read the manual, but still I am not sure how it works. It says

> `-e pattern`, `--regexp=pattern`
>
>   Specify a pattern used during the search of the input: an input
>   line is selected if it matches any of the specified patterns.
>   This option is most useful when multiple
>   `-e`
>   options are used to
>   specify multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash
>   (‘
>   `-`
>   ’).

But I don't understand how this is different from any regular grep without `-e`.

Here is the code I used to figure that out:

```sh
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % cat testgrep
warning
critical
error
passage
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep -e "warning|critical" testgrep
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep "warning|critical" testgrep
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep -e 'warning|critical' testgrep
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep 'warning|critical' testgrep
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep -e "warning\|critical" testgrep
warning
critical
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % grep -e 'warning\|critical' testgrep 
warning
critical
warning|critical
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

As you can see, they seem to behave in exactly the same manner. Is my understanding correct that they are pretty much the same thing except you can use `-e` to search multiple patterns at the same time, just like you can with the `|` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run

```
 grep -e "search1" -e "search2"
```

Grep searches for both term 1 and term 2 (ie it returns lines matching either search 1 or search 2 or both), where as running the same command without -e errors - ie the -e allows for multiple different patterns to be specified seperately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. So practically, I could achieve the same thing with the | operator, right? saving me a few key strokes?

Comment: There are corner cases where this is not practical - the man page lists "patterns starting with a -"  but for the most part I post they are pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer and as you surmised, `grep -e p1 -e p2` is equivalent to `grep -E 'p1|p2'`; I can think of a very few times I might prefer one form over the other, both forms work.

But also, as the man page says, it can protect an expression starting with a dash, and there are not many other good ways to do this.  In otherwords, `egrep -e -test`.

I think this option may also be there for consistency with other commands, for instance, `sed -e` and `awk -e`.

Comment: It's the same as `p1|p2` only with `-E` otherwise it's the same as `p1\|p2` as correctly shown in the Q, a bit less convenient to type, and anything involving `|` must be quoted to work at all, also less convenient. The main other way to use a pattern beginning with hyphen is to make it a trivial char-list like `grep '[-]p1' file` and for traditional shell behavior (not nullglob or failglob) it also works without the quotes if the pattern is otherwise safe; whether this is a _good_ way is a matter of opinion.

Comment: So `grep .-p1` misses dashes at the beginning of the line.  `grep ^-p1` misses dashes in the middle of lines.  I don't consider either of these alternatives better than `grep -e -p1`, and `grep '[-]p1'` is so much better than `-e` that it saves 2 characters.  There's quite a few other ways, but why not just use `-e`?  Anyway, it's nice to have lots of options, not sure why you are so hostile to `-e`, not like we're arguign to remove it.